# How do I follow a link in Arangodb/AQL optionally?

Tags: arangodb

I have a query right now that fetches from a single collection

```
FOR d in feed_item
   FILTER d.ingested>@when
   SORT d.score DESC
   LIMIT 50
   RETURN d
```

I'd like to fetch data from another collection,  say,

```
FOR d in feed_item
   FOR j IN INBOUND judgement_of
      FILTER d.ingested>@when
      SORT d.score DESC
      LIMIT 50
      RETURN {d:d, j:j}
```

but there may or may not be an edge in the judgement_of collection.  If there is no edge I want j to be null,  like the LEFT JOIN in SQL.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to fetch the optional data. Something like this:

```
FOR d in feed_item
   LET j = FIRST(FOR dd IN INBOUND judgement_of d RETURN dd)
   FILTER d.ingested>@when
   SORT d.score DESC
   LIMIT 50
   RETURN {d:d, j:j}
```